# Do I need a transit visa for Ukraine for a layover of 22 hours?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, schengen-visas, ukraine, kyiv

I am an Indian passport holder travelling to Berlin (TXL) from New Delhi (DEL). I am going through Ukrainian International Airlines which has a layover of 22 hours in Kiev (IEV).

My question is, do I need a transit visa beforehand if I want to leave the airport or if not can I stay in the airport without a transit visa? Another question is, is it possible for me to talk to the immigration officer to grant me a conditional single entry visa for a day at the airport (I heard somewhere that it's possible in some countries)?

I have German National visa till December (although I don't think it matters).

Comment: Which airport is that, IEV or KBP?

Comment: @WhatHiFi It's IEV, but does it matter?

Comment: It can matter. Transit facilities at airports can vary, and it's common in many countries for international transit without visa to only be available at specific airports or in and between specific terminals. The information I have from Timatic is that it is only possible at KBP, though I suspect this is out of date and I'm trying to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A visa is not required to stay in the transit zone:

> A visa is not required to transit through the Ukraine. The traveler must be in possession of a passport valid for 6 months beyond travel dates, a round-trip or onward ticket, and a valid visa for the next destination (if required).

(Source: [Travisa](https://ukraine.travisa.com/VisaInstructions.aspx?CitizenshipID=US&CountryID=UA&TravelerTypeID=TR&ResidenceID=US&PartnerID=TA))

If you want to exit the airport, you need a visa. You can apply in the [embassy of Ukraine in India](https://india.mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/services/visas).

Comment: That Travisa site is one of the many unofficial sites that give out bad information. In this case it seems to be partly due to poor website design. It seems to have given you a URL that refers to US citizens rather than Indian citizens. It's best to avoid this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Indian passport, you will need to apply for Ukrainian visa [here](https://visa.mfa.gov.ua/).
Unfortunately for you, they don't provide e-visas for Indian nationals.